# Unable to deserialize when inheriting from IList<T> or IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I've got the following class which is used to deserialize an XML feed....

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("forecast")]
public class ForecastCollection : IList<Weather>
{
    private List<Weather> _List = new List<Weather>();

    #region Implementation of IList<T>

    public IEnumerator<Weather> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _List.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(Weather item)
    {
        _List.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _List.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(Weather item)
    {
        return _List.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(Weather[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _List.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(Weather item)
    {
        return _List.Remove(item);
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _List.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public int IndexOf(Weather item)
    {
        return _List.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Weather item)
    {
        _List.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _List.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Weather this[int index]
    {
        get { return _List[index]; }
        set { _List[index] = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    public Weather Today
    {
        get
        {
            if (Count > 0)
            {
                return this[0];
            }

            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Could not retrieve todays weather from forecast");
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("simpleforecast")]
    [XmlArrayItem("forecastday")]
    public List<Weather> Forecast
    {
        get { return _List; }
        set { _List = value; }
    }
}
```

When I deserialize the feed, it doesn't seem to set the Forecast property so when I access Today, the exception is thrown. However, if I remove the inheritance from this class, it deserializes correctly.

EDIT: So to reiterate, it appears as though it only deserializes correctly when ForecastCollection doesn't inherit from something which implements IEnumerable

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong and the best way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not inherit from `Collection<Weather>`?

Comment: I think you need to specify the type of the collection in the attribute too.

Comment: Can you add code for serialization/deserialization?

Comment: @leppie, I've added ,Type = typeof(Weather) to the XmlArrayItem attribute, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: var xmlDoucment = new FileStream(@"c:\weather.xml", FileMode.Open);
            var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ForecastCollection));
            var ds = (ForecastCollection)formatter.Deserialize(xmlDoucment);

Comment: The `Forecast` property is useless, since you already expose its content by implementing `IList<T>`... Just initialize the `_List` field to a new list in the constructor, and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of that whenever you use `IEnumerable<T>` ,an iterator class would be generated by compiler in behind and that class is not `serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

With a blank `Weather` class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Weather
{
    // Nothing
}
```

following code works:

```
ForecastCollection collection = new ForecastCollection();
ForecastCollection collection2 = null;

collection.Add(new Weather());
collection.Add(new Weather());
collection.Add(new Weather());
collection.Add(new Weather());
collection.Add(new Weather());

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ForecastCollection));
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    xs.Serialize(stream, collection);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    collection2 = (ForecastCollection)xs.Deserialize(stream);
}

Boolean success = (collection2.Count == 5); // True
```